# Expand pandas dataframe date ranges to individual rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, explode, date-range

I have to expand a pandas dataframe based on start date and end date, into individual rows.

Original dataframe is as below

[image: ORIGINAL DATAFRAME]

My final dataframe should be repeated for each day between start and end date of individual rows.The result needs to be expanded for each date while the other columns except 'startdate' and 'enddate' is preserved.

For instance , the first row with startdate = 01-Jan-20 and enddate 15-Jan-20 should be expanded as 15 seperate rows representing one date in the series as shown in the sample resultant datafarame here:

[image: EXPECTED RESULTANT DATAFRAME]

I tried with the solution of itertuples to iterate over the dataframe and break the ranges to individual dates, but the solution is slow when the size of the dataframe is large.

Any optimal solution on this is highly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take the time to read this post on [how to provide a great pandas example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) as well as how to provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and revise your question accordingly :)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Use [`pandas.date_range`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.date_range.html) in a list comprehension ,then use [`DataFrame.explode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html) *(you need to be using at least pandas `v 0.25.0` for the `explode` method)*:

```
# Minimal example setup
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'TRIPNAME': ['HIGHSEASON', 'LOWSEASON', 'MEDSEASON'],
    'TRIPCAT': ['H', 'L', 'M'],
    'STARTDATE' : ['01JAN20', '16SEP20', '29JAN20'],
    'ENDDATE': ['15JAN20', '30NOV20', '19JUL20'],
    'FARE': [345, 280, 250]
})


df['DATE'] = [pd.date_range(s, e, freq='d') for s, e in
              zip(pd.to_datetime(df['STARTDATE']),
                  pd.to_datetime(df['ENDDATE']))]

df = df.explode('DATE').drop(['STARTDATE', 'ENDDATE'], axis=1)

print(df)
```

[out]

```
      TRIPNAME TRIPCAT  FARE       DATE
0   HIGHSEASON       H   345 2020-01-01
0   HIGHSEASON       H   345 2020-01-02
0   HIGHSEASON       H   345 2020-01-03
0   HIGHSEASON       H   345 2020-01-04
0   HIGHSEASON       H   345 2020-01-05
..         ...     ...   ...        ...
2    MEDSEASON       M   250 2020-07-15
2    MEDSEASON       M   250 2020-07-16
2    MEDSEASON       M   250 2020-07-17
2    MEDSEASON       M   250 2020-07-18
2    MEDSEASON       M   250 2020-07-19

[264 rows x 4 columns]
```

Comment: what if some of the datranges are empty and you want to skip them